# Help Replacing White Rodgers 1F866-344 Thermostat with Nest

Tags: nest

I have a dual zoned Heat Pump system in my house.  Each zone is controlled by a White Rodgers 1F866-344 Thermostat.  I took a picture of the connections (there are 8 wires in use) and would like to replace these thermostats with Nest thermostats. The nest wiring diagram shows that it has 6 receptacles for wires, but as you can see in the picture of the thermostats I am wanting to replace, there are 8 wires in use.

Would someone be able to help me determine where I should plug these wires into the nest based upon the picture of my current thermostat's wiring?  Thank you so much!

PS: I am not an electrician nor do I have any idea what I am doing ;)
[image: White-Rodgers 1F866-344 Thermostat's Wiring]

[image: Nest's Wiring Diagram]

---

Edit: Here is a picture of the thermostat showing the exposed letters.  It appears to me that there is a red "jumper" wire of some sort connecting RC to RH. However, if you look at the Nest Learning Thermostat, the distance from RC to RH is much longer than what that little "jumper" wire can connect to.  Thanks again for your help with this[image]

Comment: You only have 6 wires coming in to the old thermostat from the cable. The extra red link which connects "RC" to (probably) "RH" can be ignored.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your furnace/air-handler please?

Answer (score 1):

After marking the wires with appropriate letter

Remove the red bridge wire from Rh to Rc and put aside, you do not need it any more with Nest. It was there for the battery operated thermostat.

Proceed in connecting the marked wires to appropriate letter on Nest.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm assuming that I just place the colored wires in their corresponding receptacles on the Nest Learning Thermostat, correct?  What about the 3 Red Wires on my current thermostat?  Where would they go on the Nest Learning Thermostat?

Comment: see my update answer. For further help take a picture when you have exposed all the letters.

Comment: It looks to me like once you account for the fact that RH and RC are jumpered, he has the right number of wires connected to the right connections to match the system to the Nest E.  Shouldn't he be able to just connect the red wire to R and ignore the jumper completely, since the jumper is essentially just converting RH and RC to a single R connection?